# Asp.net Create a Captcha on Modal popup window of jQuery and refresh and validate it

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net, captcha

How can I Create a Captcha control with in a Modal popup window  which can refresh using ajax and jquery form  validation also on  that  Captcha  .

Thanks

Comment: Is that a question or a statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.google.com/recaptcha. This supports AJAX refresh and jquery validation as well.